# Automatically Display Posts Sorted by Catgory or Tag Taxonomy with WP Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a video post type for a client and as part of this they would like a video overview page that would display up to 3 videos for each category with an option to view more.

I can easily make a way for a user to manually add categories to the page to create the video previews sorted by category, but I would like to automate this.

So if for example a category is created and a video is added using that category it would just show up on the overview page without having to manually add the new category to the overview page.

Any help is appreaciated, thank you!

Comment: I don’t think WP’s standard query mechanisms allow for an easy way to say “give me X posts from each category.” You’ll probably have to start off by getting the list of categories first here, and then make a query to fetch the latest X posts for each of them individually.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data, you could of course also get _all_ posts, and then loop over all categories, and inside only output the posts that are in the current category via a second loop.